# printing via network gives garbage

Tags: windows-7, windows, printing

I have a Lexmark X543 printer and am running windows 7. If I use USB2 as connection and connect the USB cable, I can print. However, if I deconnect the USB cable and set the connection to the printer's IP, I can print, but only garbage. Using a differrent computer, printing via the network works. Any ideas what is going on?

Comment: First guess: The driver on the one computer is bad - update it to the latest.

Comment: ... or the driver setup is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely a driver issue.  Open print management and delete the printer itself, the drivers, and the network port and try reinstalling again using the drivers from the lexmark website.  If you still have issues i have had some luck by unchecking bidirectional support in the ports tab or unchecking "enable advanced printing features" in the advanced tab.